# Twitter Bootstrap syntax errors

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have configured `Twitter Bootstrap` with my `Asp.net MVC 3` application.But when I look at the `bootstrap.css` It's having lot of syntax issues like shown below.

I am using `Visual studio 2010 with CSS 3 enabled`.

**Error List 1:**

[image]

**Error List 2 :**

[image]

**Error List 3 :**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Folder structure after adding Bootstrap into my MVC project is as below.

[image]

How to get rid of above issues ?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using? And how are you generating the css? Are you using it directly from the project or are you generating it yourself from the less files? If it's from the less files, which tool are you using to generate the css?

Comment: @levelnis I am using latest Version 2.2.2. Actually I have added it directly without doing any modification.Just add "bootstrap.css" into my project.I will update my post to show the folder tree after adding the bootstrap content.

Comment: I don't get those errors when I view the css file in VS2012 - I have some recollection of having similar problems with the css intellisense parser in VS2010 when using Bootstrap. You might find it easier to work with the less files directly and not worry so much about the generated css in Visual Studio if you can't switch to VS2012

Comment: @levelnis Yes I am working on vs 2010 with css 3 enabled.You meant that can't I work with css without using less file with vs 2010 with Bootstrap ? B'cos when we are having this much of errors How can I reliable on this Bootstrap css file ? Any workaround for this without going to vs 2012 ?

Comment: The errors aren't actually CSS errors - it's the VS2010 intellisense parser that can't cope with them. I'm not working with 2010 at the moment so I can't play around with the settings and see whether I can stop those errors from appearing. Could your CSS be being parsed as 2.1 rather than 3 by VS?

Comment: I'd just like to add that the CSS intellisense in VS2010 is just awful. try running the css through http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input . i agree with @levelnis they aren't css errors. just VS being VS.

Comment: @levelnis When I put css 2.1 then it's having more errors.So I am having this question.If those errors are vs 2010 parser errors then will It effect final out put of the web page ? B'cos my web page class attribute also does not recognized those css styles as valid.

Comment: The parsing of the css rules by the client browsers is independent of the parsing by VS, so it's not an indication of the validity of the css per se. If everything renders as you expect in the browsers and platforms you're targeting, then that's the only thing that's really important.

Comment: @levelnis OK sure.Must be the problem is with the vs 2010 parser.I saw that they have (ms) mentioned about discontinuity of the  css 3 parser with vs 2010 since this month.May be the only solution is vs 2012.Will see.Thanks for very useful information.

Comment: No probs - will summarise into an answer to help future searchers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've encountered stems from the fact that VS2010 has buggy CSS intellisense. Viewing the bootstrap.css file in VS2012 is much improved, having far fewer parse errors reported. Neither of these 2 parsers are necessarily an indication that the CSS in invalid though. Deciding upon and then testing bootstrap-specific style rules across your target browsers and platforms is a far stronger indicator of the validity of those style rules. You should run your CSS through an external validator, such as mentioned by @kolin, if you're concerned about whether it's valid. The ultimate test is always how it renders across browsers.

Comment: I have to mentioned one thing here.That is @kolin mentioned external validator is also giving 623 errors for the "bootstrap.css".I don't know why ? Any way vs 2012 having better parser means that we have to move with latest.That is may be the only option. Thanks for the useful information.